# Active Storage: Cannot create image preview of video attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rails-activestorage

I have a Rails model which has a video active storage attachment. Now, when I want to create an image preview for this attachment, the preview is seemingly created, but the result is a video, not an image, as it should be. The entire process worked until recently, despite the code not changing. My code looks something like this:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :video # The video attachment is fine and can be retrieved and viewed

  def get_preview
    if video.attached? and video.previewable? # => true
       img_preview = video.preview(resize: "800x1400").processed # Returns an active storage instance with the file type mp4 instead of the expected png thumbnail
       return img_preview.service_url # Fails with exception (see next snippet)
    end
  end
```

This is the exception that is thrown when I try to retrieve the preview's url:

```
MiniMagick::Error: `identify -format %[orientation] /tmp/ActiveStorage20191128-4-1t9vihl.png[0]` failed with error:
2019-11-28T17:02:42.618871+00:00 app[worker.1]: identify-im6.q16: improper image header `/tmp/ActiveStorage20191128-4-1t9vihl.png' @
```

Has anyone encountered this before? The documentation for the Active Storage preview API is virtually non-existent, so I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Do you have FFMpeg installed? it's required to extract the preview https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Preview.html

Comment: @arieljuod Yes, ffmpeg is installed and `which ffmpeg` returns a valid path